# Fill out multi-dimensional array using Julia

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I am trying to fill out a  multi-dimensional array. For example, `X[1]`  is a vector  contains all values `k*h[1]` where `k=0,...,floor(Int,15/h[i])+1`. I didn't arrive to solve this problem.

```
`h=[0.01 0.02 0.04 0.08 0.1 0.2 0.5 0.8]
X=[k*h[i] for k in 0:floor(Int,15/h[i])+1 for i in 1:8]`
```

I got this error
[image]

Comment: Jupyter notebooks save the state of all variables from all previously-executed cells, so it is impossible to know if the iteration variable `i` in your example has been defined before. In fact, I bet `i` was set to something somewhere else in the notebook, because if you run your code in the REPL, you will quickly see that the real problem is that `i` is not defined in this expression. The order of iteration is backward: see what happens when you try `for i in 1:8 for k in ...` instead.

Comment: Thank you @PaSTE! Yes it works using `h=[0.01 0.02]
x=[k*h[i] for i in 1:2 for k in 1:floor(Int,15/h[i])+1]` but I didn't get the form of array as a matrix. For example x[1] is  the first row,  x[2] is a the second one, and so on.

Comment: even if you sort it out (e.g. changing the order of `i` and `k` loops you cannot create a matrix - the size over `k` is different over each `i`. Do You want to create a`Vector` of `Vector`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `Vector` of `Vector`s instead of a 2D `Array` as noted by @PrzemyslawSzufel. This is because `X[1]` has length that's different from `X[2]`, that's different from `X[3]`, etc.

The real error, then, is that `i` is not defined. The variable `i` is defined in the second comprehension, `for i in 1:8`, but, it's not accessible in the first comprehension. To solve this, we can insert the first comprehension inside 2 brackets to make it as one element of the second comprehension. Finally, we'll get `X[1]` as a vector containing all values `k*h[1]`, etc.

**Note:** In Julia, `h = [0.01 0.02 ...]` is a `Matrix{Float64}` and not a `Vector`. So, you should use `h = [0.01, 0.02, ...]` instead for `Vector`s. Also, the range `0:floor(Int,15/h[i])+1` is similar to `0:15/h[i]+1` because the default step is `1`, except that the second range has `Float64` values.

```
h = [0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8];

X = [[k * h[i] for k in 1:15/h[i]+1] for i in 1:8];

X[1]
1501-element Vector{Float64}:
  0.01
  0.02
  0.03
  0.04
  0.05
  0.06
  0.07
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you all for this clear answer! By the way,  I did an alternative one like `t[i]=[k*h[i] for k in 0:floor(Int,15/h[i])]` and do loop for `i` however your code is  absolutely the best!